# How jquery knows what dataType to return

Tags: jquery

I am using php to generate some json data wrapped in a html5 tag and i am not sure how jquery knows what data type to return.

This is the php

```
echo '<section id="stuff">';
echo json_encode($jsonData);
echo '</section>';
```

To get the data inside the section tag,i am treating my data this way

```
$.ajax({                                     
      url: 'getdata.php',                         
      data: "",     
      dataType: 'html',                
      success: function(data)         
      {
       var thedata = $(data).filter('#stuff').html();
       var jobject = JSON.parse(thedata);
       for(var i = 0; i < jobject.length; i++) {
   var item = jobject[i];
```

Here is specified that the dataType would be html but when i specify json,nothing gets displayed but the get is successful.

I then use jquery get shorthand and everything works.

```
$.get('getdata.php', function(data) {
       var thedata = $(data).filter('#stuff').html();
       var jobject = JSON.parse(thedata);
       for(var i = 0; i < jobject.length; i++) {
       var item = jobject[i];
```

Did jquery shorthand method guess my dataType was HTML?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataType gives jQuery a hint as to the response type from the server, in your first example jQuery expects the response to be text (well, HTML with script tags evaluated), but when you specify JSON in the datatype jQuery will attempt to convert this to a JavaScript object, which will fail.

In the latter example, jQuery has guessed the response to be JSON, ignored the filter and conversion to HTML and dealt with `$(data)` as a JavaScript object.

Overall, I see no reason to encapsulate the JSON object you're encoding from the server within HTML, this should be structured and parsed as any other object.

```
<section id="stuff">
'{ "Object": [{"Value" : "1", "Text" : "2 in HTML"},{"Value" : "2", "Text" : "3 in HTML"}] }'
</section>
```

---

```
  var json = '{ "Object": [{"Value" : "1", "Text" : "2"},{"Value" : "2", "Text" : "3"}] }'

   var jobject = JSON.parse(json);
   for(var i = 0; i < jobject.Object.length; i++) {
       var item = jobject.Object[i];
       alert(item.Value);
   }

 var jsonInHtml = $("#stuff").html();

 var jobject = JSON.parse(jsonInHtml);

 // A JavaScript object won't be frmed at this point

for(var i = 0; i < jobject.Object.length; i++) {
       var item = jobject.Object[i];
       alert(item.Value);
 }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DbEy9/)

Comment: The reason i am wrapping json that way,is because i have to get lots of data at one go,like from 4 tables all related.Have you any idea how i can get the data from all 4 in one json object instead of structuring the 4 distinct data sets into four unique tags?.